# PDF Engine that supports Unicode

Tags: delphi, pdf-generation, delphi-xe

I need a Delphi Library to generate a PDF (commercial and preferably with source). Furthermore the lib should support Unicode (UTF-8). 
I already found http://www.quickpdflibrary.com/. Are there any experiances with this lib?

**Update1**:
My experiences so far:
 [QuickPDF converting a PDF to an Image: letters move in eachother](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956041/quickpdf-converting-a-pdf-to-an-image-letters-move-in-eachother)

**Update2**:
My best experiances so far are with gnostice: http://www.gnostice.com/eDocEngine_VCL.asp

**Update3**
At last I think QuickPDF is the best library. It has this one downside with the moving letters if the font isn't embedded with the pdf (see Update1).

Comment: I'd be astounded if there existed a PDF library that didn't support Unicode

Answer (score 3):

GnostIce has the [eDocEngine](http://www.gnostice.com/eDocEngine_VCL.asp) and [PDF Toolkit](http://www.gnostice.com/pdftoolkit_vcl.asp) VCL components.  AFAIK, those support Unicode.

[WPCubed](http://www.wpcubed.com/products/wpdf/generic/index.htm) also has a Delphi wrapper component for generating PDFs, but I don’t know if those support Unicode.

Answer (score 3):

My experience with QuickPDF has been first rate. The library is fast, extensive and easy to use. The forum is very responsive and newbie users are shown respect. It's an important part of my toolkit.

Having said all that, I should add that my use of the library has been mostly in the area of filling in government forms and it does that very well. I plan to also create a bunch of reports with it and then automatically combine them all with an outline of hyperlinks.

Answer (score 2):

I can also recommend Debenu QuickPDF.  Very comprehensive feature set, good support.

Since you mention Delphi XE and that you need "UTF-8" support, I should point out that the current library functions all use native UnicodeString parameters to pass string variables. Support for handling any UTF-8 data would therefore come from Delphi, not the library.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you already found your library (so what is the point of the question?), our Open Source [SynPDF library](http://blog.synopse.info/tag/PDF) supports Unicode (including [font fallback](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2012/07/10/Better-Unicode-support-in-Reports-and-PDF-generation)), and even glyph shading via [Uniscribe rendering](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/05/06/Synopse-PDF-engine-1.7.2).

It works from Delphi 6 up to XE3, has full source code, and can work from a `TCanvas` property: that is, you can draw your content using regular VCL draw commands, or render a metafile. It is statically linked (no external DLL needed), is very fast, and produce small pdf content.

Some users, on our forum, state that this Open Source library is better than most "commercial" versions. Open Source is freedom - even if the company does not maintain the library in the future, anyone can fork the project and update it. You can get the source now, and check out if it feels your needs. Open Source is just safer, in some cases.

Comment: more than once I feel inclined to download and check the software you recommend, but then I follow the links and I find very difficult to reach a download of what you talk about, since you link a blog and the page usually lacks a download link. The page you linked today, have a download link, but for the whole mORMot project, not SynPDF, so I understands it is a sub-set, but I'm not interested in the whole, so it looks like I can't download what you advertise here.

Comment: Click on the download link and you have a link at the 5th position, named PDF Engine.

Comment: Thannks Arnaud, I just can't remember was what I was looking the last time, but I remember I surfed there for an hour before giving up. Now, I noticed the first download link, but missed the second. :)

Comment: Mormot is well documented but synpdf wev pages should be enhanced... sorry for the confusion. But you have all unit api documented in the code comment. Forum has some sample code.

Comment: I am trying the SynPDF Framework right now. How is the support for PDF/a in SynPDF?

Comment: Okay it does support PDF/a