# QuickPDF converting a PDF to an Image: letters move in eachother

Tags: delphi

Quick PDF has a feature to convert a PDF into an Image:

```
iNumPages := PDFLibrary.PageCount();
PDFLibrary.RenderDocumentToFile(300, 0, iNumPages, 0, 'H:\temp\quickpdf_testimage_6_new.bmp');
```

If this feature  is executed the letters move (with some PDF sources) in each other. In the following there is a PDF and the resulting JPG:
[image]
[image]
PDF: http://www.baunetz.de/aip/2001/tunnel.pdf

Now there is a problem: in the resulting Image the Letters move in eachother.

**Update**:
I have cause of the Problem:
"
This PDF contains a font (OfficinaSans-Book) that is not embedded in the PDF so Quick PDF substitutes Arial instead which has thicker characters.

This is a common problem with PDF's and many PDF viewers.  The best solution is to create the PDF with embedded fonts for any of the non standard fonts that are used in the PDF."
http://www.quickpdf.org/forum/topic2478_post10369.html#10369

**Update 2:**
The only PDF Engine so far that has no Problems with 'lettes moving in each other' is the foxit DLL.

Comment: that the letters move in each other in the Image. I'll write that a little clearer

Comment: Just a note, space between characters is known as kerning.

Comment: What version of Quick PDF?  The latest is now Debenu PDF library 9.12. I was going to suggest that you open a support ticket with Debenu, which you can do at http://www.quickpdflibrary.com/support/support-query.php; I see you have already posted the same question in the user-to-user forum (again without specifying your build version). That is not the best way to get support from the developers, however

Comment: i am using the latest Version of quick PDF. I think i have an possible cause for: a unsupported font?

Comment: Frugi, please answer your own question, then mark that as the correct answer (IIRC there is a 2-day delay before you can do that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have cause of the Problem: " This PDF contains a font (OfficinaSans-Book) that is not embedded in the PDF so Quick PDF substitutes Arial instead which has thicker characters.

This is a common problem with PDF's and many PDF viewers. The best solution is to create the PDF with embedded fonts for any of the non standard fonts that are used in the PDF." http://www.quickpdf.org/forum/topic2478_post10369.html#10369

**Edit**:
A possible solution would be to use MultiMaster fonts if the font wasn't found on the system. Adobe uses this technique. But i haven't found a way to implement that with quickpdf.